# How can I update window title color in Windows 11

Tags: windows-11

I want to change my Title Bar Colour in File Explorer in Windows 11 to look like windows 7. The program folders I have fixed using WinAeroTweaker. But System folders are still all white and difficult to tell one part of the window from another.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I use title bar colors in Themes bu File Explorer is not amenable to that. I do not know if you can do what you want.

Comment: How do title bar colors differ between system and program folders? This seems strange,

Comment: Microsoft has been hiring redundant folks from Apple, and they are showing off their prowess, or at least they think they are. And Microsoft want you in bed with them and they want to own you.

Comment: Is this really a problem?  How many system folders do you routinely open?  Please provide examples of system folders.